# Xamarin Toolbar Hamburger Menu Break

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting an unhandled exception when I try to access the hamburger menu on my Android simulator. The exception is:

```
Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView occurred
```

It was working until very recently, but reverting all my code changes today doesn't fix the problem. I don't think the problem is with my code.

I don't know what I did to cause this, but I was playing around with different Navigation types when the problem came up. Couldn't find relevant information about the error online.

Comment: Have you added, updated or removed some NuGet package from your solution?

Comment: Ugh, I forgot about a package I added. Don't think I even used it, but it broke this widget. Thanks for reminding me; removed and it works again. Appreciate the help!